# How do I calculate B/2?

Tags: matrices

Let's say I have **Matrix B** =
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 4\\
        3 & 2\\
        0 & -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

How would I **calculate** **B/2**? Do I just divide each element of **B** by **2**? Please help!

Comment: There isn't such a thing as the division of a matrix by a scalar (or by anything really). I suppose that what you mean is $\frac12 B$. In which case yes, that's what you do.

Comment: @ahmedhussein So B/2 is miswritten? or the same as 1/2B?

Comment: It's miswritten; probably intended as $\frac12 B$.

Comment: @ahmedhussein $B/2$ is a common and acceptable notation for $\frac 12 B$

Comment: @nonbee yes. You just divide every element of $B$ by $2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, could you write up your excellent comment as an answer, please, so the question doesn't continue to show no answers?

Answer (score 0):

See the comments. Indeed, given a matrix $B$, one computes $B/2$ by dividing all *entries* of $B$ by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 4\\
        3 & 2\\
        0 & -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ then 
$$\frac{B}{2}= \frac12\begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 4\\
        3 & 2\\
        0 & -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 2\\
        1.5 & 1\\
        0 & -0.5\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

So yes, just divide all the elements by $2$.